# Regex to get everything

Tags: java, regex

I want to print all the stack trace after `Servlet failed with Exception java.lang.NullPointerException`. I also used `.contains("Servlet failed with Exception")`
but that doesnt always work as few of the NPE don't have stack trace. Please help!!

```
public class PatternMatching {
    public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "<Jul 5, 2017 4:14:28 PM GMT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@1215989071[app:CeCBS module:/shop path:/shop spec-version:2.5]] "+
    "Servlet failed with Exception" +
    "java.lang.NullPointerException" +
    "at xyz.commerce.catalog.CatalogAccessTools.findLeadItemByBundleSku(CatalogAccessTools.java:770)" +
    "at xyz.commerce.catalog.PerformanceMonitoringUKCatalogAccessTools.findLeadItemByBundleSku(PerformanceMonitoringUKCatalogAccessTools.java:436)"+
    "at xyz.commerce.catalog.CatalogAccessTools.findLeadItemByBundleSku(CatalogAccessTools.java:760)"+
    "at xyz.commerce.catalog.PerformanceMonitoringUKCatalogAccessTools.findLeadItemByBundleSku(PerformanceMonitoringUKCatalogAccessTools.java:426)"+
    "at xyz.commerce.catalog.controller.PlansListingController.setChooseAPlan(PlansListingController.java:1505)"+
    "Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace " ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Regex = "^Servlet failed with Exception.*\\bat\\b.*";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);


       if(m.find())
       {
           System.out.println("Print succesfull");
           //System.out.println(m.start());
           //System.out.println(matcher);
       }
       else
       {    
           System.out.println("Print unsuccesfull");
       }
    }
}
```

It should just print unique stack trace

```
at xyz.commerce.catalog.CatalogAccessTools.findLeadItemByBundleSku(CatalogAccessTools.java:770)
at xyz.commerce.catalog.PerformanceMonitoringUKCatalogAccessTools.findLeadItemByBundleSku(PerformanceMonitoringUKCatalogAccessTools.java:436)
  at xyz.commerce.catalog.CatalogAccessTools.findLeadItemByBundleSku(CatalogAccessTools.java:760)
  at xyz.commerce.catalog.PerformanceMonitoringUKCatalogAccessTools.findLeadItemByBundleSku(PerformanceMonitoringUKCatalogAccessTools.java:426)"+
    at xyz.commerce.catalog.controller.PlansListingController.setChooseAPlan(PlansListingController.java:1505)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: between what and what?

Comment: Edited. I wanted print all the stack trace after `Servlet failed with Exception java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Here's the thing, your actual stacktrace might have newlines or other whitespace in there which your hard-coded string does not have.

Comment: Any Regex possible to read everything after `Servlet failed with Exception   java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @self.Fool any solution worked?

Comment: Actually I am writing a bot program which would return the stack trace after the except. For eg:  `Stack trace:- at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
Class name:- WebAppServletContext.java
Line No :- 3681`

Comment: And I have used this pattern `Pattern p= Pattern.compile("at (.*)\\.(.*)\\(([^:]*):?([\\d]*)\\)")` and printing 
ClassName and lineNo using the group method to get the stack trace details.
 But it is working for only a few exceptions. It doesn't print the correct className and lineNo for
 `at xyz.ces.upgrade.manager.integration.generic.service.HeritagePkgServiceManager.checkPackageResponse(HeritagePkgServiceManager.java:248)`
Any Suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important thing to know is that you will need to use the `Pattern.DOTALL` parameter to the `Pattern.Compile` function in order for the `.` to match newlines. In that case, however, you might not be able to use the `^` before the word 'Servlet' (I can't remember for sure, so you can mess with it), because it might not match the beginning of the line. Other than that, I personally would probably capture the Exception type with a `\\S+` (note the capital 'S'), which matches a group of 1 or more non-whitespace characters. As a whole then, I would suggest

```
String regex = "Servlet failed with Exception\\s+\\S+\\s+(.*)$"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
```

The data on your error will be found in matching group 1 of your matcher object after running `m.find()`.

I would point out that this won't work on you example as you have it because you don't include whitespace between the several concatenated strings, but it should work on real output.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this one:

```
Servlet failed with Exception(.|\\n)+
```

`(.|\\n)+` for new line and more or any character

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/TGFlvA/1)

Answer (score -1):

You could just try splitting on `"java.lang.NullPointerException"`:

```
String whatYouWant = EXAMPLE_TEST.split("java\\.lang\\.NullPointerException")[1];
```

## Demo

This is a quick a dirty approach which would appear to meet your needs.  A better, albeit more verbose, approach would be to use a regex to extract each line of the stack trace:

```
String pattern = "at .*?\\(.*?\\)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = r.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
while (m.find()) {
    sb.append(m.group(0)).append("\n");
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

## Demo

Note that I tuned the regex pattern to your actual stack trace *string*, which probably isn't what you would be parsing in reality.  A better pattern would be something like this:

```
String pattern = "\\bat .*?\\(.*?\\)";
```

This would be safer to match `at` at the start of each line.

Comment: The above pattern `"\\bat .*?\\(.*?\\)"` prints everything after "at". I am happy with this. But I want `Servlet failed with Exception java.lang.NullPointerException` this too and then print the stack trace.

Comment: @self.Fool I'm not inclined to change my answer at this point.  Perhaps you could just assert that the null pointer exception appears, and then use my answer to identify the rest of the stack trace?

Comment: Well I modified it to `at (.*)\\.(.*)\\(([^:]*):?([\\d]*)\\)`  which gives me the class name as well as the line number from the stack trace. Thanks much.